# Hide shipping cost in checkout page

Tags: php, woocommerce

I i have three shipping methods in my checkout page as follows.

1. shipping by us  =  table rate
2. Shipping by customer = Free shipping
3. Local Pickup

what is want is fi customer select freeshipping or local pickup table rate cost need to invisible. when they select table rate again it should show the cost again. I used below code

````
function Ws_lk_hide_shipping ( $rates, $package ) {      
// Only unset rates if free_shipping is available
if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping:12'] ) ) {
        unset( $rates['table_rate:5'] );
}     return $rates;}```


but above code hide the entire table rate line. so can not select it again.
````

Answer (score 0):

Instead of unsetting the $rates['table_rate:5'], try setting it to 0.00 or "Free Shipping", if it accepts string value, like below.

```
function Ws_lk_hide_shipping ( $rates, $package ) {      
   // Only unset rates if free_shipping is available
   if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping:12'] ) ) {
        $rates['table_rate:5'] = 0.00;
   }     
   return $rates;
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding the actual issue, try above method if that solves the issue.

Comment: HI thank you can you please explain me a bit your suggestion. what my requirement is if customer select the free shipping courier charges need to be zero and if he select the courier charges back then its should show the charges.

Comment: Thank you its giving a fatal error in checkout page.

Comment: Fatal error might be cause of other parts of code, Thank you.